# Show that the halting problem is decidable for one-pass Turing machines

Tags: formal-languages, computability, turing-machines, check-my-proof

$L=\{<\!M,x\!>\, \mid M's \text{ transition function can only move right and   } M\text{ halts on } x \}$. I need to show that $L$ is recursive/decidable.

I thought of checking the encoding of $M$ first and determine whether its transition function moves only right (Can I do that?). If so then try to simulate $M$ on $x$ for $|Q|+1$ steps, if it stops then $<\!M,x\!>\, \in L$ otherwise it is not.

Is this correct?

Comment: By R do you mean Regular Languages?

Comment: No, to recursive languages. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: See [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/lm-l-where-m-is-a-tm-that-moves-only-to-the-right-side-so-l-is-regul).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume $Q$ is state set of $M$. If so, this runtime bound does not make much sense; in particular, a Turing machine with three states can move to the end of the input and check whether $x$ is an even number; it is clearly not enough to wait three steps.

The next question is whether there *is* a computable bound on the runtime of halting one-pass machines. Unfortunately, there is not: $M$ might be nondeterministic and halt after an arbitrary amount of steps.

So we determinise $M$ while simulating (that is computable) and look for a bound for all paths. Now we are getting somewhere: after having consumed the input, there are two cases. Either $M$ halts or it enters a loop. As it only moves right (into empty tape), such loops can be detected.

> Putting things together, we simulate a determinisation of $M$. We run every branch until $x$ is consumed¹ and then for another $|Q|\cdot|\Sigma_T|$ steps, $Q$ the set of states and $\Sigma_T$ the tape alphabet of $M$. At this point $M$ has either stopped or loops (in this branch), which we detect by a pair of current state and tape symbol occuring for the second time. We only have to check finitely many branches up to a computable bound, therefore $L$ is recursive.

---

1. $M$ might loop here already if not moving the head is allowed, but that can be detected, too.

Comment: See [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/lm-l-where-m-is-a-tm-that-moves-only-to-the-right-side-so-l-is-regul).